# How to install PHP on Visual Studio Online Environment?

Tags: debian, php, visual-studio-code, linux-on-azure

Any ideas how to get PHP to work on [Visual Studio Online - environment](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/services/visual-studio-online/) (preview) for development and test purposes?

I believe it is Debian 9 based and tried to install it by [this](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-php-on-debian-9/) method (and many other but all with same result).

In the end it looks like this (no matter if I specify the php version or not, install from .deb file or sources):

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package php is a virtual package provided by:
  php7.3 7.3.11-1~deb10u1 [Not candidate version]
  uwsgi-plugin-php 2.0.17.1+8+0.0.3+b3 [Not candidate version]
  php7.3 7.3.4-2 [Not candidate version]
  php7.0 7.0.33-0+deb9u6 [Not candidate version]
  php7.0 7.0.33-0+deb9u3 [Not candidate version]
```

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: not exactly this... but it is now possible to use custom and predefined docker containers on VSO environment.. So that was my workaround.. There are some repositories which you can use as starting point on github.. Hope this helps..